# Unclosed Group Error with Parentheses when Replacing an Expression

Tags: java, regex, replace, parentheses

So I am trying to make a custom variant of the `ScriptEngineManager`'s `engine.eval()` by reading a string before evaluating it. I want to turn the expression **3(4)** into **3*(4)** so the `engine.eval()` can read it. So I attempt using this method:

```
String string = 3(4);
String[] numbers = string.split("\\)|\\*|/|\\+|-");
if (numbers[i].contains("(")) {
    val = numbers[i].split("\\(");
    if (val[0].equals("")) {
        val[0] = "1";
    }
    String replace = val[0] + "*(" + val[1];
    string = string.replaceFirst(numbers[i], replace);
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the error that *"Unclosed group near index 3"
"3(4"* which I have debugged to find that the line `string = string.replaceFirst(numbers[i], replace);` is causing the problem. Either I need to do something else or I just don't understand the error, as I do not understand what I am doing wrong as my desire is to replace the first instance of **3(4** within the string **3(4)** with **3*(4**. I do not want to close the expression as something like **3(4-x)** would cause the error of **3*(4)-x)**.

Thank you for your time and have a good day :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*replaceAll(String **regex**, String replacement)* - so argument *"3(4"* is treated as regular expression. To use it as it is you need to quote it: `Pattern.quote(numbers[i])`.

Comment: Thank you! I am still new to the regex library, so missing this isn't a surprise, even though I thought I was using `replaceFirst(oldChar, newChar)` for it, or is that not used because of the variables that I was using?

Comment: If your expression does not contain special chars it doesn't matter if you quote it or not.